# Is there a way to send a PATCH request in Google Contacts API?

Tags: api, contacts, google-contacts-api

I'm using [Google Contacts API v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) to integrate contacts with my web server. I've gotten everything working pretty well, but I'd like to be able to do partial contact updates instead of the full ones (for example, update just one phone number without having to reupload the whole contact). The full update uses an HTTP PUT request ([as shown here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#updating_contacts)), but there is no mention on that page about partial updates. However, I found [this](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#PartialUpdate) Google Protocol Reference that says that partial updates can be done by issuing a PATCH request instead of a PUT. But when I do that, it gives me a 404 "Not Found" error. So, does that mean that it's not possible to do partial updates in the Contacts API? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: I don't think you can do partial update or PATCH request with contacts API. In the documentation its mentioned, also as you mentioned, To update a contact, first retrieve the contact entry, modify the data and send an authorized PUT request to the contact's edit URL with the modified contact entry in the body.

Comment: The problem is that I only need to work with a small subset of the contact fields, and I want to avoid having to parse the whole Google contact and then re-upload it. I'm afraid of "missing" some contact data at some point, and when the contact gets re-uploaded without that data, it'll be gone without me even realizing it.